# Can't determine what selector to use on td inside of table inside of div

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm having trouble determining what selector to use access the CSS properties.  Here's my code:

My jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#columnDay1').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $('#columnDay1').mouseover(function () {
            $('td.calendarHeader').css("background-color", "#a43802");
        });
        $('#columnDay1').mouseout(function () {
            $('td.calendarHeader').css("background-color", "#37322e");
        });
    });
</script>
```

My html:

```
<div class="contentColumnDay1">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="columnDay1">
    <tr>
        <td class="calendarHeader">
            <p><span class="dayHeader">Day 1</span><br />August 15, 2011</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="labelDay1"></asp:Label>
</table>
```

I'm trying to access the `.calendarHeader` CSS property `background-color`. I have tried `#columnDay1.calendarHeader` and it does not work. I'm banging my head on the desk.

Any help?

Comment: <table tbody tr td.calendarheader> is one of the way there are many better ways thou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
$('#columnDay1').mouseover(function () {
    $('td.calendarHeader').css("background-color", "#a43802");
});
```

try

```
$('#columnDay1').mouseover(function () {
    $('td.calendarHeader', this).css("background-color", "#a43802");
});
```

`td.calendarHeader` will reference every td of class "calendarHeader". You need to give it a context of `this` or `$(this)` to specify that you only want to find the td.calendarHeader inside of the element that you just mouseovered. Alternately, you could do `$(this).find('td.calendarHeader').css`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#columnDay1 .calendarHeader').css('background-color');
```

I think you are missing a space between the selectors

Answer (score 0):

Because `contentColumnDay1` is a class, you can't use `#contentColumnDay1` (# is for id), use `.contentColumnDay1 td.calendarHeader` instead.